# Does Flink 1.2 support python in streaming programming?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

Refter to the python programming guide online:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/batch/python.html
I didn't see any material related to streaming programming like kafka connector and so on.

Also from the git hub examples(https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming), I didn't see python codes either.

If it does support python in streaming programming, could you show me some examples to start with?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an open PR for adding python support for the streaming API: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3838 I'm not entirely sure whether it works in its current state, but it is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flink 1.2 does not support Python for streaming. 
Flink 1.3 doesn't support it either.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Flink 1.4 will support Python for streaming, you can see the recent PR [FLINK-5886 - Python API for streaming applications](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3838).